# C3js row data, custom colors

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

I'm using c3js to make a chart with row data and want to use specific colours.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x:'x',
        rows: [
             ['x','Winter 2007-2008','Winter 2008-2009','Winter 2009-2010'],
             ['2013-01-01',12,30,3],
             ['2013-01-02',123,200,22],
             ['2013-01-03',21,100,54],
             ['2013-01-04',32,400,23],
             ['2013-01-05',12,150,12],
             ['2013-01-06',34,250,15]
        ],
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is all good, except I wish to set each line as a custom colour.

With column data, [this is simple](http://c3js.org/samples/options_color.html):

```
data: {
    x:'x',
    columns:[[]]
},
color: {
        pattern: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e']
}
```

Can this be achieved with row-oriented data?

Answer (score 6):

Try setting color function to the chart as shown below:-

```
    color: function (color, d) {
        // d will be 'id' when called for legends
        var colors = {           // Mapping for dataseries to color code.
            'Winter 2007-2008': '#ff0000',
            'Winter 2008-2009':'#00ff00',
            'Winter 2009-2010':'#0000ff'
        };
        if(typeof d === 'object') {
            return colors[d.id];
        }else {
            return colors[d];
        }
        //return d.id && d.id === 'data3' ? d3.rgb(color).darker(d.value / 150) : color;
    }
```

Working example:- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chetanbh/c3y1cgxb/)

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  All other examples I found did not apply to my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Color pattern should work:

```
color: {pattern: ['#ff0000','#00ff00','#0000ff']},
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvzv646m/).